# C# Calling VB Function which calls Windows API Function passing NULL

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, winapi

I am trying to work with a library to interface to the Windows Scheduler.
http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx

THe library was written in VB.NET and I am using C# to call it.

So my c# is calling this

**otask.SetAccountInfo(null,null)**

in VB this is defined as

**Public Sub SetAccountInfo(ByVal accountName As String, ByVal password As String)
   m_ITaskObj.SetAccountInformation(accountName, password)
End Sub**

and the vb code is calling a function defined like this

**Sub SetAccountInformation(<In, MarshalAs(LPWStr)> ByVal wszAccountName As String, <In, MarshalAs(LPWStr)> ByVal pwszPassword As String)**

So my question is how to I pass a NULL to the function as it fails as below with different values

**otask.SetAccountInfo(null,null)**

**Value does not fall within the expected range when vb is calling the m_ITaskObj.SetAccountInformation(accountName, password)**

EDIT

This is the function I want to call

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Chris

Comment: You are passing null to both parameters or just the password?

Comment: !!! I can't read !!!   I was passing null to both but I was supposed to pass "" for the username and NULL for the password - Thanks

Comment: Exactly, that's what the documentation says. Glad it helped.